# PCRE: Difference between .* and .*? in regular expressions

Tags: pcre

I was wondering, why `.*` and `.*?` is not the same in PCRE regular expressions (for example in PHP's preg_match(). Dot `.` is symbol for any possible character and `*` is symbol for 0 to infinity repetition. Why is there symbol `?` which means 0 to 1 repetition? However it is not obviously the same, because `.*?` is not interchangeable with `.*`, but I can't see logic difference, I have to always try what works and what does not work in certain case. I suppose that `.*` should match nothing to anything and `?` is redundant, because it specify that `.*` can be 0 or 1 times - but zero times is empty string and empty string should be matched by `.*` too.

Can anyone explain me what is the exact difference and show me short example?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> i love wantons because they are tasty snacks

In the above string, let's say you try to match it with `i.*s`. The result would be the entire string, because this is called a `greedy match`. It matches from the first instance of `i` until the last instance of `s`.

If you were to use the non-greedy modifier `?`, like `i.*?s`, then you would result in the following:

> i love wantons

This is because the non-greedy `?` modifier only matches until the first instance of `s`.

Answer (score 0):

`*` is a *greedy match* - in other words, match zero to many times, as many times as possible.  `*?` is a *minimal match* - in other words, match zero to many times, as few times as possible for the rest of the pattern to make sense.  Similarly, `+?` is a minimally-matching version of `+`.

Consider the string `this is "quoted" and this is "also quoted"`.  The regular expression `".*"` would match one result, `"quoted" and this is "also quoted"`; `".*?"` would match twice, `"quoted"` and `"also quoted"`.